# CodeIgniter deployed on an Apache server in a subdomain - Redirect Looping

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am deploying a codeigniter app onto a subdomain which is hosted by a 3rd party apache server. When accessing the page it constantly refreshes and then the browser tells me there is a Redirect Loop occurring. I know it has to do with the Apache conf settings and the custom .htaccess file I use but I have no idea how to fix it.

Current .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Your rules are fine, something else is broken

Comment: My rules are fine but if the server has rules in the vhosts conf file wouldn't they conflict with mine? Thus this behavior?

Comment: Maybe, but without actually seeing them, who knows?

Comment: Check your access and error logs

Comment: Seems as if it's not finding any files what-so-ever. The error file shows File does not exist: /home/myname/subdomain/login. Then after it doesnt find that it has the same thing for the favicon and 404 errors that they are not found. Hm...

Comment: Ive got it to the point where it now says "The requested URL /login was not found on this server."

Answer (score 0):

Try another `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

if not - try changing the last line to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Also make sure you've set `$config['index_page']` in config.php to `''`

Comment: Both just have a redirect loop.. I have no idea what to do!

Comment: Try starting with a clean codeigniter install by downloading it from codeigniter's website.

Comment: I just did that and the clean install works. However, I think it becomes an issue when we introduce the .htaccess because of conflicting rules (Apache conf. Vs. CodeIgniter .htaccess)

Comment: Have you set `$config['index_page'];` to `''`?

Comment: Now I installed the .htaccess (the one you gave me) on the clean install and it works.. What could be going on?

Comment: Hard to say, I don't know your config, I don't know what you changed last time

Comment: Yeah, I've tried all the different config settings. I dont understand why the default CI settings and .htaccess work on a clean install but not on mine.

Comment: So what is the problem now? Can you copy folder-by-folder from your install to the fresh one starting from `config` folder itself and constantly monitoring to find the file that's causing redirects?